# Defining best 5 cards

Tags: texas-hold-em

So last night me and a group of friends were playing Texas hold 'em. This one particular hand caused an argument and I wanna see how others would call it. So I will keep it short and sweet

Player A has K 6
Player B has K 5

The board shows K,Q,J,9,2

My question is? Would this be a split pot or does the 6 count as the 5th best card?

Answer (score 1):

In no-limit hold 'em 5 cards are chosen from the 5 cards on the board and the 2 cards from your hand to make your hand. In this case both players have the same pair, so kickers are relevant. Because a hand is made of 5 cards, there are 3 kickers in play. The Q, J and 9 are higher than the 6. Therefore both players have a pair of kings plus Q, J, 9 kicker. The 6 doesn't count towards the hand. Conlusion: it is a split pot.